# Exercise $11$.D.c from Willard: «Prove that if every subnet of $(x_λ)_{λ\inΛ}$ has a subnet converging to $x$ then $(x_λ)_{λ\inΛ}$ converges to $x$»

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, nets

In the text *General Topology* of Stephen Willard is ask to show that if $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ is a net such that every its subnet has a subset converging to $x$ then $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ converges to $x$.

So to prove the statement I tried to work with a particular subset so that given the neighborhoods system $\mathcal U(x)$ of $x$ then I observed that the relation
$$
(\lambda_1,U_1)\preccurlyeq(\lambda_2,U_2)\longleftrightarrow \lambda_1\preccurlyeq\lambda_2\wedge U_2\subseteq U_1
$$
for any $(\lambda_1,U_1),(\lambda_2,U_2)\in\Lambda\times\mathcal U(x)$ makes $\Lambda\times\mathcal U(x)$ a directed set. Now is not complicate to show that the projection  $\pi_\Lambda$ onto $\Lambda$ of $\Lambda\times\mathcal U(x)$ is an increasing cofinal map so that the position
$$
x_{(\lambda,U)}:=x_\lambda
$$
for any $\lambda\in\Lambda$ and for any $U\in\mathcal U(x)$ defines a subnet of $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$. So we observe that if $x_{(\lambda,U)}\to x$ then for any $U\in\mathcal U(x)$ there exists $(\lambda_0,U_0)\in\Lambda\times\mathcal U(x)$ such that
$$
x_{(\lambda,U)}\in U
$$
for any $(\lambda,U)\succcurlyeq(\lambda_0, U_0)$ but $(\lambda, U_0)\succcurlyeq(\lambda_0,U_0)$ for any $\lambda\succcurlyeq\lambda_0$ so that
$$
x_\lambda=x_{(\lambda,U_0)}\in U
$$
for any $\lambda\succcurlyeq\lambda_0$ which means that $x_\lambda\to x$. So I thought that I could prove the statement proving that if a subnet of $(x_{(\lambda, U)})_{(\lambda,U)\in\Lambda\times\mathcal U(x)}$ converges to $x$ then also $(x_{(\lambda, U)})_{(\lambda,U)\in\Lambda\times\mathcal U(x)}$ converges to $x$ but unfortunately I was not able to do this.

So how solve the exercise? Could someone help me, please?

Comment: Isn't that essentially the same proof as for sequences? (like mostly when you work with nets) So suppose $(x_\lambda)_\lambda$ does not converge to $x$, therefrom you can construct a subnet which "stays away from $x$", which in turn, by assumption, has a subnet which converges to $x$. This should easily give a contradiction, doesn't it?

Comment: @nicrot000 Sorry, but I do not know an analogous result for sequences. Anyway if $x_\lambda$ did not converge to $x$ then there exists $U\in\mathcal U(x)$ such that for any $\nu\in\Lambda$ there exists $\lambda_\nu\ge\nu$ such that $x_{\lambda_\nu}\notin U$, right?

Comment: So for any $\nu\in\Lambda$ through the identity map (which is increasing and cofinal, right?) we define the subset $$x_\nu:=x_{\lambda_\nu}$$ which is not in $U$ so that $x$ cannot be a cluster point for $(x_\nu)_{\nu\in\Lambda}$, right?

Comment: However by assumption there exists a subnet of $(x_\nu)_{\nu\in\Lambda}$ converging to $x$ so that $x$ is a cluster point for $(x_\nu)_{\nu\in\Lambda}$ which is a contraddiction.

Comment: So does this argumentations work?

Comment: I guess you hide a lot of what is going on behind some fancy language. I fact you can just define an increasing sequence in $\Lambda$ which particularly defines a subnet. Since $(x_\lambda)$ does not converge to $x$ you find $U\in\mathcal{U}(x)$ such that for any $\lambda\in\Lambda$ there exist $\mu>\lambda$ with $x_{\mu}\notin U$. Thereby you can inductively define a sequence of $(x_{\lambda_n})_n$ (aka subnet of $(x_\lambda)$) which completely lies outside $U$. By assumption is must also contain a subnet/subsequence which converges to $x$, particularly,

Comment: it must have all but finitely many (particularly one) element in $U$

Comment: @nicrot000 Sorry I did not completely understand: how define inductively a sequence starting form a **generic** net?

Comment: So to summarize: if $x_\lambda$ does not converge to $x$ then there exists $U\in\mathcal U$ such that for any $\nu\in\Lambda$ there exists $\lambda_\nu\preccurlyeq\nu$ such that $x_{\lambda_\nu}\notin\Lambda$.

Comment: Now are you stating that the map $$\varphi:\Lambda\owns\nu\to\lambda_\nu\in\Lambda$$ is increasing and cofinal? Could you show this, please?

Comment: Let $\lambda_1\in\Lambda$ such that $x_{\lambda_1}\notin U$. This exists but what I just wrote. Given $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\in\Lambda$ with $\lambda_1<\dots<\lambda_n$ and $x_{\lambda_1},\dots,x_{\lambda_n}\notin U$ you find $\lambda_{n+1}>\lambda_n$ with $x_{\lambda_{n+1}}\notin U$ by the same argument. $(x_{\lambda_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence (and a subnet of $(x_\lambda)$ outside of $U$.

Comment: Okay, so $(x_{\lambda_n})_{n\in\Bbb N}$ does not converges to $x$ and in particular $x$ is not a cluster point but it has a subsequence converging to $x$ so that $x$ is a cluster point and thi is impossible. Does this you want mean?

Comment: No:  if $(x_\lambda)_\lambda$ does not converge to $x$ then there exists $U\in\mathcal{U}(x)$ such that for any $\nu\in\Lambda$ there exists $\lambda>\nu$ such that $x_{\lambda}\notin U$.

Comment: @nicrot000 Oh, sorry: I wrote $\preccurlyeq$ instead of $\succcurlyeq$.

Comment: To you last comment: it is important that $(x_{\lambda_n})$ cannot have a subsequence that converges to $x$ since it completely lies outside $U$.

Comment: Anyway now it is clear; only one question: I can apply induction even if $\Lambda$ is finite, right?

Comment: and you wrote $x_{\dots}\in\Lambda$ in the end, but I guess that was also a typo.

Comment: @nicrot000 Oh right? So about induction instead?

Comment: Yeah, you should exclude the case of finite $\Lambda$. But that should be easy, isn't the limit of a finite net just it's last element?

Comment: Ore more generally, if $\Lambda$ has a largest element $\lambda_{\text{max}}$, then $x_{\lambda_{\text{max}}}$ is the limit of $(x_\lambda)$

Comment: @nicrot000 I do not know this: indeed a directed set is not totally ordered.

Comment: However, for the problem it doesn't matter. What I wrote above as "$(x_\lambda)$ does not converge to $x$" provides you with a larger index, so it doesn't matter whether $\Lambda$ is finite or not.

Comment: @nicrot000 Anyway this perhaps this is not a problem because a subnet is defined by an increasing (not strictly increasing!!!) and cofinal map.

Comment: So given $\lambda\in\Lambda$ for $n=0$ there exists $\lambda_0\succcurly\lambda$ such that $x_{\lambda_0}\notin U$; now for $n=1$ there exists $\lambda_1\succcurlyeq\lambda_0$ such that $x_{\lambda_1}\notin U$. So by induction we can make an increasing sequence (not necessarly injective!!!) $(\lambda_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ on $\Lambda$ such that $x_{\lambda_n}\notin U$ for any $n\in\Bbb N$ so that the statement follows proving that this sequence is cofinal, right?

Comment: However this seems not trivial: so what can you say about?

Comment: So how find for any $\lambda\in\Lambda$ an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $\lambda_n\succcurlyeq\lambda$?

Comment: So does you have an idea?

Comment: Okay, I must withdraw my comment on the fancy language, that was a quickshot and indeed there are some subtleties.

Comment: @nicrot000 Do not worry.

Comment: Maybe you can save that by, given $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ pairwise different you, by non-convergence of $(x_\lambda)$, have a $\lambda_{n+1}\ge\lambda_n$ with $\x_{\lambda_{n+1}}\notin U$. Then either you can choose $\lambda_{n+1}\neq\lambda_n$ or somehow show that $\lambda_n$ is already the largest element of $\Lambda$, I guess.

Comment: However, for sure there are some people in this forum which can give you a more profound answer to that.

Comment: @nicrot000 Perhaps I found an answer: what do you think about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ does not converge to $x$ then there exists $U\in\mathcal U(x)$ such that for any $\lambda\in\Lambda$ there exists $\nu_\lambda\in\Lambda$ such that $\nu_\lambda\succcurlyeq\lambda$ and such that $x_{\nu_\lambda}$ not lies in $U$ so that the set
$$
\text{N}:=\{\nu\in\Lambda:x_\nu\notin U\}
$$
is not empty. Now for any $\nu_1,\nu_2\in\text{N}$ there exists $\nu\in\Lambda$ such that
$$
\nu\succcurlyeq\nu_1,\nu_2
$$
and thus what initially observed ensures that there exist $\lambda_\nu\in\Lambda$ such that
$$
\lambda_\nu\succcurlyeq\nu\quad\text{and}\quad x_{\lambda\nu}\notin U
$$
but this proves that $\lambda_\nu\in\text{N}$ and so we conclude that $\text{N}$ is a directed set: that is, we conclude that the restriction of the preorder $\preccurlyeq$ on $\Lambda$ makes $\text N$ a directed set. Now we observe that the inclusion map
$$
\iota:\text{N}\ni\nu\to\nu\in\Lambda
$$
is trivially increasing and moreover it is cofinal too because what initially observed trivially implies that for any $\lambda\in\Lambda$ there exists $\nu_\lambda\in\text{N}$ such that $\nu_\lambda\succcurlyeq\lambda$. So through the position
$$
x_\nu:=x_{\iota(\nu)}
$$
for any $\nu\in\text{N}$ we cand define a subnet $(x_\nu)_{\nu\in\text N}$ of $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ whose elements are disjoint from $U$ so that $x$ cannot be a cluster point for this subnet. However by assumption there exists a subnet of $(x_\nu)_{\nu\in\text N}$ converging to $x$ so that any subnet can be converge to $x$, but this is impossible since no of its elements is contained in $U$. So, for these reasons, we finally conclude that $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ converges to $x$.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: @nicrot000 Okay, fine. Anyway thanks very much for your input: you helped a lot!

Comment: It is correct. Perhaps you could elaborate a bit more why $N$ is directed (given $\nu_1, \nu_2 \in N$, take $\nu \in \Lambda$ with $\nu \ge \nu_1, \nu_2$ and then find $\lambda_\nu \ge \nu$ with $x_{\lambda_\nu} \notin U$). Moreover you do not need to consider cluster points; it is clear that a net all of whose elements are not in $U$ (as all subnets of your $N$-subnet) cannot converge to $x$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Okay, thanks for advice: I edited the answer. Did I write right what you suggested?

Comment: I suggest to do it as follows:  ... we can define a subnet $(x_\nu)_{\nu\in\text N}$ of $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ whose elements are disjoint from $U$. However by assumption there exists a subnet of $(x_\nu)_{\nu\in\text N}$ converging to $x$, but this is impossible since no of its elements is contained in $U$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Okay, fine: I just edited the answer again. Thanks very much for your courteousness: you was very kind with me. Thanks again. See you soon.