# An example showing that a quotient space of an hausdorff space is not hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, examples-counterexamples, quotient-spaces

Let be $\mathscr P$ the partition of $[0,1]^2$ defined through the position
$$
\mathscr P:=\big\{\{x\}\times[0,1]:x\in\Bbb Q\big\}\cup\big\{\{(x,y)\}:(x,y)\in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q\times[0,1]\big\}
$$
So I ask to prove that the quotient topology of $\mathscr P$ is not hausdorff: unfortunately I have not many ideas about although I worked sometimes. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: What is $\mathbb P$ here?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net $\Bbb P$ is the set of irrationals, that is $\Bbb P:=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net So have you some ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your partition consists of all line segments $L_x =  \{x\} \times I$ with $x \in \mathbb Q \cap I$ and all singletons outside $(\mathbb Q \cap I) \times I$. Let $p :  I^2 \to \mathscr P$ denote the function assigning to each $(x,y)$ the member of $\mathscr P$ containing it. Give $\mathscr P$ the quotient topology induced by $p$.

Take any irrational $\xi \in I$ and define $\xi_i = p(\xi,i) = \{(\xi,i)\} \in \mathscr P$ for $i = 0,1$. Clearly $\xi_0 \ne \xi_1$. Assume that there exist disjoint open neighborhoods $U_i$ of $\xi_i$. Then the sets $p^{-1}(U_i)$ are disjoint open subsets of $I^2$. Since $(\xi,i) \in p^{-1}(U_i)$,  there exist open neigborhoods $V_i$ of $\xi$ and $W_i$ of $i$ in $I$ such that $V_i \times W_i \subset p^{-1}(U_i)$. Pick any rational $\eta \in V_1 \cap V_2$. Since $(\eta,i) \in p^{-1}(U_i)$, we have $p(\eta,i) \in U_i$, thus $L_\eta = p^{-1}(p(\eta,i)) \subset p^{-1}(U_i)$. Therefore the $p^{-1}(U_i)$ are not disjoint, a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand this: if $$p^{-1}\big(p(\eta,1)\big)\subseteq p^{-1}(U_1)\quad\text{and}\quad p^{-1}\big(p(\eta,0)\big)\subseteq p^{-1}(U_0)$$ then why $p^{-1}\big(p(\eta,1)\big)\subseteq p^{-1}(U_1)$ and $p^{-1}\big(p(\eta,0)\big)\subseteq p^{-1}(U_0)$ are not disjoint? could you expalain this, please? Forgive my confusion.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Because both contain $L_\eta$.

Comment: But $L_\eta$ is not different when $i=0$ or $i=1$?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro No. We take $\eta \in V_1 \cap V_2$, i.e, $\eta$ *sufficiently close* to $\xi$ to achieve that $(\eta,i) \in p^{-1}(U_i)$. But then $L_\eta \subset p^{-1}(U_i)$ since inverse images under $p$ are unions of members of $\mathscr P$.

Comment: Sorry but I am bit confused: if $(\eta,1)$ and $(\eta, 2)$ are different then why $L_\eta$ is uniquely determined?

Comment: $L_\eta = \{\eta\} \times I$.

Comment: Okay, now it is all clear: question upvoted and approved. Thanks for your assistance. Anyway could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4442887/exercise-11-d-c-from-willard-prove-that-if-every-subnet-of-x-%ce%bb-%ce%bb-in%ce%9b-h) too? Perhaps sometime ago I found an answer to a question I posed but I would like to have the opinion of a people more expert than me about its correctdness. Forgive the bother.